# init-scripts in autoyast to autodeploy Suse Linux server

Tags: shell, init-script, suse, yast

I'm deploying a base SLES11.1 server using autoyast. What I want to achieve is to install some packages on it after the deployment. So I use the init-script in the autoyast control file. Here is the my init-scripts part:

```
<scripts>
  <init-scripts config:type="list">
     <script>
        <location>nfs://10.198.31.71/InsRepository/initScript.sh</location>
        <filename>initScript.sh</filename>
        <rerun config:type="boolean">true</rerun>
     </script>
  </init-scripts>
</scripts>
```

And here is my initScript.sh code

```
 #!/bin/bash

 zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.1/repo/oss Opensuse
 zypper --no-gpg-checks --non-interactive in \
        --force-resolution gcc openssl-devel e2fsprogs-devel

 curl -L http://cpan.org | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus Text::CSV Date::Parse File::Path
 wget --directory-prefix=/tmp ftp://10.198.31.71/VMware-vSphere-CLI-5.1.0-780721.i386.tar.gz

 tar -zxvf VMware-vSphere-CLI-5.1.0-780721.i386.tar.gz

 export http_proxy=
 export ftp_proxy=

 ./vmware-vsphere-cli-distrib/vmware-install.pl --default
```

But when I finished deployment, I found nothing run. The thing is, I can run the script on a freshly deployed server.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it is running in daemons. So I need to wait long time to finish the script.